# For loop iteration to continue from the end value of first iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for an output in the following manner:
If my inputs are

```
starting_value = 8
ending_value = 20
```

I want output as

```
8 13    ##8+(5) = 13
14 19   ##start of next iteration should be 13+1 = 14, and then 14+(5)
```

I wrote a for loop for this:

```
for i in range(8,20):
    start = i
    end = i+5
    print(start,end)
    i = end+1
```

But I'm getting wrong result:

```
8 13
9 14
10 15
11 16
12 17
13 18
14 19
15 20
16 21
17 22
18 23
19 24
```

Is there something wrong in my for loop, Any better pythonic way to do this?

Comment: The reason why your for-loop doesn't work, is because `i` takes a new value from the `range(8, 20)` iterator on each iteration. The statement `i = end + 1` doesn't do anything. `for` in python is a `for-each` loop & not a traditional C for-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by using a step size of 6 in your range:

```py
starting_value = 8
ending_value = 20
step = 5

for i in range(starting_value, ending_value, step + 1):
    start = i
    end = i + step
    print(start,end)
```

Output:

```
8 13
14 19
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple shifting:

```
for i in range(8, 20, 6):
    print(i, i+5)
```

The output:

```
8 13
14 19
```

---

The same with predefined variables:

```
start, end, step = 8, 20, 5

for i in range(start, end, step+1):
    print(i, i + step)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
i = 8
while i <20:
    start = i
    end = i+5
    print(start,end)
    i = end+1
```

output:

```
8 13
14 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it:

```
starting_value = 8
ending_value = 20

start = starting_value
end = starting_value
while end+1 < ending_value:
  end = start + 5
  print(start, end)
  start = end + 1
```

Output:

```
8 13
14 19
```